# Application close unexpectedly after calling web service if result is null

Tags: android

i use the following lines in my program to call web service and taking the result

all thing is fine, but if any time if a web page has no content it has null or white space then application close unexpectedly.

```
           1) SoapPrimitive result=null;
           2) androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
               //upto this line program run smoothly
           3) result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

plz suggest me, how i handle this, because i can only check the result value after completion of 3 line, but error occur before completion of line number 3.

i checked the envelop before result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); but it not have any null, but i have still same problem

waiting for reply

Comment: can you post some relevant log about the error from LogCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for null. and if null happen than create a new object and pass some default value or anyting like that. You can than detect that null value and can handle in code.

don't try to handle it by "try catch" becouse it is very costly in mobile application.

Answer (score 2):

May be your `envelope` is just `null`. Check it before doing anything with it.

Comment: i checked the envelop before result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); but it not have any null, but i have still same problem

Comment: So, you need to post your stacktrace to determine there the problem is.